# How can we prove that $\mathbb{N^2}$ has the same cardinality as $2\mathbb{N} + 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

How can we prove that $\mathbb{N^2}$ has the same cardinality as $2  \mathbb{N} + 1$?

I've thought about using Cantor's theorem and mapping every element in a coordinative system, am I going to the right direction or am I wrong?

Comment: I would do this in stages. Showing that $\Bbb{N}$ has the same cardinality as $2\Bbb{N}+1$ is a standard/textbook example (possibly without the $+1$). Showing that $\Bbb{N}^2$ has the same cardinality as $\Bbb{N}$ is a more advanced textbook example, but still standard (diagonal method is common). Compose the two! The composition of two bijections is another bijection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an alternative way if you don't want to explicit a bijection : you can use Cantor-Bernstein Theorem by proving that the two following maps are injective :

- $\varphi : 2\mathbb{N}+1 \rightarrow \mathbb{N}^2$ defined by $\varphi(n)=(n,0)$
- $\psi : \mathbb{N}^2 \rightarrow 2\mathbb{N}+1 $ defined by $\psi(n,m)=2^{n+1}3^m+1$.

Comment: I see, but what if we define $\mathbb{N}$ as $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$, could there still be a bijection from what I am asking in the original question?

Comment: @Gabro Well, just replace $\varphi$ in my answer by $\varphi(n)=(n,1)$...

Answer (score 1):

One classical bijection from $\mathbb{N}^2$ to $\mathbb{N}$ is $$(x,y)\mapsto \frac{(x+y)(x+y+1)}{2}+y.$$
You can thus here try
$$(x,y)\mapsto 2\left(\frac{(x+y)(x+y+1)}{2}+y \right)+1.$$

Comment: If you would not mind to tell me, how can we prove that this is a bijection?

Comment: The "difficult part" is to show the classical bijection (because then you just compose two bijections), let's note it $f$. To show the injectivity, if $(x,y)\neq (x',y')$, you want to show that $f(x,y)\neq f(x',y')$. Separate in case $x+y=x'+y'$ and $x+y<x'+y'$. To show the surjectivity, let $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x,y)=m$. Remark that there exists a unique $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\leq m<\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}$. Set $y=m-\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ and $x=k-y$.

Answer (score 1):

Simple bijection is given by $f(a,b)=2^a(2b-1)+1$ (assuming $0 \not\in \mathbb{N}$).

(bijectivity: use fundamental theorem of arithmetic to show every even integer can be uniquely written as $n=2^s d$ with $s\geq 1$, $d\geq 1$ odd)

Comment: I've proved that the function is injective, but I can't get the hang of proving its surjectivity, could you prove it?

Comment: @Gabro Surjectivity comes from the "every integer can be..." part of the theorem (injectivity comes from the "uniquely" part). Explicitly for any $2m+1$ factor out the maximal power of $2$ from $m$ and you have $m=2^s d$ for some odd $d=2k-1$, then you have simply $2m+1=2^{s+1}(2k-1)+1=f(s+1,k)$